# Python: Randomly Select One Key From All Keys in a Dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, random, key

Let's say I have accessed my dictionary keys using `print (hamdict.keys())`

Below is a sample output:

[image]

I know my dictionary list has a length of 552 elements.  I want to randomly select one "key" word from my list and assign it to the variable "starter".  I tried to do this with the code below (note: I have a dictionary called hamdict):

```
random_num = random.randint(0, len(hamdict.keys())-1)
print (random_num)
print (hamdict.keys()[random_num])
```

I'm able to get a value for random_num so that seems to work.  But the second print returns the following error:

[image]

How can I fix my code?

Comment: random.choice(list(hamdict))

Comment: [**Please do not upload images of text (code/input/output/errors, or otherwise) on Stack Overflow**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). Please [edit] your question, pasting all text into the question with [correct formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 1):

`my_dictionary.keys()` returns a generator-like object, not a list. You can probably get what you want by converting it to a list first

```
print(list(hamdict.keys())[random_num])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
random.sample(hamdict.keys(),1)[0]
```

The sample() function randomly selects a given number of items from a list or iterator.  Contrary to the choice function, it supports iterators so you don't need to make a list out of the keys beforehand.  The result is a list so you need to get its first item from the output (hence the `[0]`).

Comment: The community [encourages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712) adding explanations alongisde code, rather than purely code-based answers. As explained [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837): "While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* this code answers the question improves its long-term value." - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/28386493)